# how i can make test rules in selenium TestNg as a select box GUI?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In testNG we run every test like this :

[image]

Or, we put a lot of test rules in XML to run all of them.

I want to make Gui panel to select every test rule that I want to run to make testers with no java selenium coding knowledge use that test rules as a Gui panel.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think such thing exist. however it's not hard to implement, if you know Python there is a web development framework flask, which you can easily configure to do what you want.

Comment: i can't do that in java implementation ?

Comment: you can do that, I am sure there must be some simple platform to create web application.

Comment: Maybe with the include and exclude labels, for each modules, help you.